# Why is the question about structuralism and categorization unclear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Question in question: [What is the relationship between categorization and structuralism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/92347/19487)

It is closed for being unclear without further guidance. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state different questions within one body title. Each of them basically comes out of nothing.

Therefore, there are two problems with the question body as asked:

1. It is unclear what your *actual question* is. If there are multiple, this is bad style as one question thread should always contain only one, concise question. If it is "what do you think/am I right?", this would be a different **valid** reason for the closure.
2. A good question should include the motivation and context, ie. why and where in your studies the question arose. This will give us a better understanding of your level and the specific needs an answer has to address. Your question just throws things at us without any of that.

Therefore, the reason may be debatable but the closure as such seems to be perfectly within our rules.

Comment: For (1), I know about the one question at a time rule, but it seems that it's more about a recommendation, not a strict rule. It depends on how the readers feels asking them in one place making it more coherent or more convoluted. (I guess it's a hermeneutics problem). For (2), do you think the discussions in the comment make it clearer on my motivation and context?